# accessing local storage variable after browser window restart

Tags: jquery, html, web-storage

I thought if I store value in localstorage and close browser window, and then open browser again, I might still be able to access the value stored in that localstorage key. Doesn't seem like the case, as I do this with following:

`localStorage.setItem('MyApp_fiat_currency', FiatCurrency);`

`localStorage.getItem('MyApp_fiat_currency')`

While the window is open when the value is set getItem returns the stored value. I close the browser window, open that again, and test in console the same getItem, and the value is `null`.

Does, that mean localstorage can not be used in this case?

I have to go with cookies then?

Thanks

Comment: Are you in private/ incognito mode?

Comment: localStorage does not clear if you close and reopen the window but sessionStorage does.

Comment: no, I'm using normal chrome browser console for testing for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage.getItem() must return the value you stored for sure.
Make sure you are not clearing the local storage at some point using: localStorage.clear()
and make sure you are using the same protocol the second time you are accessing your page meaning https:// and http:// will have different localStorage values.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll be using simple file:/// accessing locally accessible .html file opened in web browser.

Comment: Tested with file:/// and this seems to work. The only difference this time was I put the code in .html file and accessed it from same location. I'll do further tests and see if I get any problem. Thanks! :)